Epistemic accounts of modal notions
I recall once reading an off-hand comment (I believe in SEP) that although there are epistemic accounts of modality, modality is generally considered a matter of metaphysics. What I assumed this meant was that there are theories that say the truth value of modal statements is determined by epistemic facts, not metaphysical facts. For example, you find a wallet, and before you look inside the wallet, the modal statement "it's possible that there is a lot of money in that wallet" is a statement about your lack of knowledge. After you open the wallet and find $3, you can still say "it was possible that there was a lot of money in the wallet" means that there was a time in the past where you had a lack of knowledge that made it possible that there would be a lot of money in the wallet.
I've done some internet searches for "epistemic modality" and similar terms, but although there are a lot of hits none of them is an epistemic account of modality. Can anyone direct me to such accounts? Is there a better term to search for?
Just to clarify, I'm looking for an account that there is no such thing as metaphysical modality and that all modality is about epistemic issues.

Does this SEP article address your question, or do you have something more specific in mind?

No different account: It has been questioned whether the epistemic and alethic modalities should be considered distinct from each other. The criticism states that there is no real difference between "the truth in the world" and "the truth in an individual's mind". An investigation has not found a single language in which alethic and epistemic modalities are formally distinguished.  But new epistemic conceivability hints epistemic modality might be weaker since conceivability doesn't necessarily imply possibility under scientific essentialism...

You mean like IEP: Epistemic Modality? Typically though, they would not say that "there is no such thing" as some other modalities, but rather that they are not the ones under consideration. Or are you interested in arguments against metaphysical modality instead?

@Conifold, yes, I'm interested in arguments that all modality is epistemic.

All modality is epistemic is too strong, there are non-alethic ones, like deontic, and nomic, etc. even among alethic ones. Quine famously maintained his rejection of metaphysical modality in the face of Kripkean orthodoxy. Geelen examines his arguments and responses to Kripke's rebuttals at length in his thesis Quine versus Kripke on the Metaphysics of Modality. For a short historical account of the controversy sympathetic to Quine's view, see Tuboly, Quine and Quantified Modal Logic.

@conifold, I'm using "modality" in the original sense, to refer to necessity and contingency. I'm looking for views that say necessity and contingency and related notions are all epistemological.
